# Remove green squiggly lines but not red lines in visual studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The squiggly green lines in VS 2019 is a bit annoying. See for example:
[image]

How to disable the display of green warnings, but not the error red type of warning in VS 2019?

I tried to go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Code Analysis Squiggles, but it disables all warnings

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251420/discussion-on-question-by-user21078706-remove-green-squiggly-lines-but-not-red-l).